# Error Implementing Acumatica REST API

Tags: rest, api, acumatica

I am currently trying to implement the use of the Acumatica REST APIs in a project I am working on. I am able to successfully log in to the application.

The issue is when I try to access additional data, customers for example, I receive the following message:  {"message": "You have been logged out because your account has been disabled. Please contact your system administrator."} in the form of a 403 error.

I checked my account permissions and I do have the System Admin Role on the account I am using to log in to Acumatica. Below is a screen shot of my postman.

[image: PostMan ScreenShot]

Comment: I wanted to add that in the above screen shot customers starts with a lower case c but I have sent requests with postman using upper case as well. Same issue.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have the admin user disabled.

Some function of Acumatica impersonate the admin user in order to complete their task. Some of these functionalities include the web services, the scheduler and the integration services.

Enabling the admin user should fix the issue you are facing.

Comment: What do you mean enable the admin user? The account I'm using has legitimate Admin Privileges as far as I can tell.

Comment: if you go to the users screen(SM201010) and find the Login "admin" this is the user that I am talking about and it is this User/Login that should be enable for it to work properly.

Comment: I was able to find it and enable it. Still though, when I try to call the API I get the same message. This may be a silly question, but do I need to also call the API with this admin account, or will the account I was given with admin privileges work?
Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You should not need to use the admin account, just have it enabled. Have you tried restarting IS? Is it still the same error message?

Comment: Yes and Yes. Seems to be an odd issue.

Comment: I didn't get an explanation but I did get confirmation from Acumatica on a ticket that the base "admin" user needs to be enabled because it is used by the contract API on some lower level functions.